# Gem therubyracer does not install in alpine docker container

Tags: ruby, linux, docker, rubygems, alpine-linux

I am trying to build a docker container with ruby using a base alpine docker image (alpine:3.11).

and I have installed the most common repositories:
`build-deps build-base make python git bash gmp-dev zlib-dev libressl-dev gdbm-dev db-dev readline-dev libffi-dev coreutils yaml-dev linux-headers autoconf`

Also, installed libv8 gem by using this command:

`gem install libv8 -v '3.16.14.16' -- --with-system-v8`

Then when I try to install therubyracer using below command :

`gem install therubyracer -v '0.12.3'`

it gives me long error message:

```
ERROR:  Error installing therubyracer:

current directory: /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/therubyracer-0.12.3/ext/v8                                                                                                                            
/usr/bin/ruby -I /usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0 -r ./siteconf20210316-1-1t6t8wp.rb extconf.rb --with-v8-dir\=/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/therubyracer-0.12.3/                                                       
checking for -lpthread... yes                                                                                                                                                                              
checking for v8.h... no
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:

        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=/usr/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
        --with-pthreadlib
        --without-pthreadlib
        --enable-debug
        --disable-debug
        --with-v8-dir
        --with-v8-include
        --without-v8-include=${v8-dir}/include
        --with-v8-lib
        --without-v8-lib=${v8-dir}/lib /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/libv8-3.16.14.16/ext/libv8/location.rb:50:in `configure': By using --with-system-v8, you have chosen to use the version  (Libv8::Location::System::NotFoundError)of V8 found on your system and *not* the one that is bundled with the libv8 rubygem. However, your system version of v8 could not be located. Please make sure your system version of v8 that is compatible with 3.16.14.16 installed. You may need to use the --with-v8-dir option if it is installed in a non-standard location         from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/libv8-3.16.14.16/lib/libv8.rb:7:in `configure_makefile' from extconf.rb:32:in `<main>' To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can be found here: /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.6.0/therubyracer-0.12.3/mkmf.log extconf failed, exit code 1 Gem files will remain installed in /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/therubyracer-0.12.3 for inspection. Results logged to /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.6.0/therubyracer-0.12.3/gem_make.out The command '/bin/sh -c gem install therubyracer -- --with-v8 dir=/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/therubyracer-0.12.3/' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

This is my dockerfile:-

```
FROM alpine:3.11
ENV BUILD_PACKAGES="curl-dev ruby-dev build-base" \
    DEV_PACKAGES="zlib-dev libxml2-dev libxslt-dev tzdata yaml-dev sqlite-dev postgresql-dev mysql-dev" \
    RUBY_PACKAGES="ruby ruby-io-console ruby-json yaml nodejs" \
    RAILS_VERSION="4.2.3"

RUN apk --update --upgrade add $BUILD_PACKAGES $RUBY_PACKAGES $DEV_PACKAGES
RUN apk --no-cache add gmp-dev libressl-dev gdbm-dev db-dev readline-dev libffi-dev coreutils yaml-dev linux-headers autoconf
RUN apk add --update --no-cache --virtual build-deps make python2 git bash libstdc++
RUN apk add alpine-sdk findutils binutils-gold yarn npm postgresql postgresql-client curl
  
RUN gem install -N nokogiri -- --use-system-libraries && \
  gem install -N rails --version "$RAILS_VERSION" && \
  echo 'gem: --no-document' >> ~/.gemrc && \
  cp ~/.gemrc /etc/gemrc && \
  chmod uog+r /etc/gemrc && \
  # cleanup and settings
  bundle config --global build.nokogiri  "--use-system-libraries" && \
  bundle config --global build.nokogumbo "--use-system-libraries" && \
  find / -type f -iname \*.apk-new -delete && \
  rm -rf /var/cache/apk/* && \
  rm -rf /usr/lib/lib/ruby/gems/*/cache/* && \
  rm -rf ~/.gem
RUN gem install bundler -v '1.17.3'
RUN gem install libv8 -v '3.16.14.16' -- --with-system-v8
RUN gem install therubyracer -v '0.12.3'
RUN mkdir /usr/app
WORKDIR /usr/app
COPY Gemfile /usr/app/
RUN bundle install
EXPOSE 3000
```

Comment: Please add your Dockerfile. It's easier to help you with these informations :)
Also use the preformated code tag, as it's more readable

Comment: At the end of the message you are given a path to the file containing the build log. Read that file.

Comment: I found libv8-alpine gem https://rubygems.org/gems/libv8-alpine/versions/6.7.288.46.1-x86_64-linux-musl or Docker file https://github.com/n0rmanc/docker-ruby-alpine-therubyracer/blob/master/2.4/Dockerfile

Comment: @Malik Added my dockerfile